# Inject all beans with a specific annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I've been using Spring for decades, but never ran into this use-case before.

Is there a way to inject all the beans annotated with a specific annotation, e.g. all beans with `@Service` or all with `@CustomAnnotation`?

The only idea I have is to inject the context, get *all* the beans and filter manually. If this is the only way, does Spring expose a method that recursively scans a class hierarchy for (meta) annotations (as most Spring annotations can be used as meta-annotations)?

Comment: Do they have to be annotated? It is possible to inject lists of a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation specifies `includeFilters` and `excludeFilters` attributes.
To scan only classes decorated with  `@Service` you could disable `useDefaultFilters` and include only the `Service` annotation :

```
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters = false,
                includeFilters = @Filter(Service.class))
```

To scan only custom annotations, you could write a similary thing :

```
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters = false,
                includeFilters = @Filter(CustomAnnotation.class))
```

As multiples classes are specified in  `value/classes` of `@Filter`, a `OR` logic is applied.

---

Note that the [`@Filter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.Filter.html) annotation accepts class(es) as `value/classes` attribute but these are interpreted by Spring according to the `type` value of `@Filter`.
By default, `type` has as value `FilterType.ANNOTATION`.
To filter on a specific annotation (as you in your case), this default value suits as you want to filter candidates on the annotation itself.

Here values defined in the [FilterType](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FilterType.html) enum class :

```
public enum FilterType {     
    ANNOTATION,    
    ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
    ASPECTJ,
    REGEX,
    CUSTOM    
}
```

Note also that `@Filter` works with  `classes/value` but not only.
You have indeed two alternative ways :

- valuing the `classes/value` attribute (as in your case)
- valuing `pattern` attribute.

The first way expects to have as `type` : `ANNOTATION`, `ASSIGNABLE_TYPE` or `CUSTOM`.
While the second way expects to have as `type` : `REGEX` or `ASPECTJ`.